# VS Code игнорирует обработку исключений try/catch

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio-code, try-catch

try игнорируется в visual studio code

```
try:
    a = 1/0
    print('Good')
except:
    print('Error')
```

[image: Как выполняется код]

При запуске к примеру в Atom'e всё работает как надо или в онлайн ide
Переустановка vs code не помогла.
Не голый try тоже не помогает

Comment: Вам нужно к слову except добавить еще и тип ошибки. То есть `except ZeroDivisionError:`

Comment: @DenisRudnitskiy Это необязательно.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В настройках дебага VS Code установлен флаг, по которому перехватываются все исключения. Тем самым не давая программе обработать их.

Запустите код, получите исключение, перейдите в дебаг и отключите флаг `User Uncaught Exceptions`. Тогда ваш `try/catch` сработает.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Замечу, что желательно указывать сам тип исключения, чтоб не ловить все подряд и обрабатывать их корректно.

```
try:
    1 / 0
except ZeroDivisionError:
    print("ZeroDivisionError")
```